# Fetching $metadata for a specific collection or entity with Odata web services in Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2016

Tags: web-services, odata, metadata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

## The environment

As part of an integration project, I need a PHP website to be able to both read from and write to Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2016's Odata services.

Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2016 uses [the Odata v3 standard](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/).

---

## The context

Now, let's take my `customer` service as an example.

#### Fetching a collection of entities

Fetching an overview of my collection of `customer` entities works fine, using a link with the following format :

```
https://<Server>:<WebServicePort>/<ServerInstance>/OData/Company(\'<CompanyName>\')/customer
```

#### Fetching a single entity

Fetching a single `customer` entity based on `id` works fine, using a link with the following format :

```
https://<Server>:<WebServicePort>/<ServerInstance>/OData/Company(\'<CompanyName>\')/customer(\'<Id>\')
```

#### Fetching the global metadata

Getting an overview of the `$metadata` for all of my services works fine (although it's lacking Json support), using a link with the following format :

```
https://<Server>:<WebServicePort>/<ServerInstance>/OData/$metadata
```

#### Fetching collection-specific metadata

Now, based on both [the Odata v3 specs](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/) and the value of the `odata.metadata` property of my customer overview service, I would expect to be able to get an overview of the `$metadata` of the `customer` entity, using a link with the following format :

```
https://<Server>:<WebServicePort>/<ServerInstance>/OData/$metadata#customer
```

This doesn't work as expected. See sub-section `The issue` below.

#### Fetching entity-specific metadata

Similarly, based on both [the Odata v3 specs](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/) and the value of the `odata.metadata` property of my dataset when retrieving a single customer, I would expect to be able to get an overview of the `$metadata` of a single field of the `customer` entity, using a link with this format :

```
https://<Server>:<WebServicePort>/<ServerInstance>/OData/$metadata#customer/@<FieldName>
```

This doesn't work as expected. See sub-section `The issue` below.

#### The issue

For some reason, everything following `$metadata` appears to be ignored. This means that the last three URLs give me the exact same output, which is not what I expected.

---

## The actual question(s)

- Is it possible to fetch the metadata of just one collection or entity, as I'm trying in sub-sections `Fetching collection-specific metadata` and `Fetching entity-specific metadata` of my `The context` section hereabove?
- If yes, what I doing wrong here? What am I missing?

Comment: It seems that you're looking for the metadata as a service. It doesn't support now in ODL, neither in Dynamics CRM. See [issue](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/181)

Comment: @SamXu : So, does this mean that the metadata is really nothing but a static file?! That would explain a lot, actually!

Comment: So far, I think so. However, metadata is useful and necessary for client. For example, OData client or similar clients can read the metadata content to generate the codes used to access the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [**@xuzhg**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3304931/sam-xu) suggested in the comments and as is indicated by Github issues like [**Support Metadata as a service (#181)**](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/181), it appears that the Odata `$metadata` are not really a dynamic service. Instead, it's just a single XML file.

This explains not only why anything after $metadata is ignored in links of format `https://<Server>:<WebServicePort>/<ServerInstance>/OData/$metadata#...`, but also why it only supports XML, and not Json (unlike actual Odata services).

Comment: Per [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5), the HTTP client is stripping the `#` and everything after it (i.e., the fragment) prior to sending the request.

Comment: Also, there is no JSON representation of the metadata because there is no JSON-based articulation of the schema for metadata ([CSDL](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part3-csdl.html)).

Comment: @lencharest : The `#` was kind of a give-away, I guess. I just didn't expect the metadata to be completely static. Much the same way, I just didn't expect the metadata of a Json service to be defined in XML. Maybe it's naive to expect more from a company like Microsoft, but having metadata for a Json service as an XML-only static file comes off as kinda rushed / sloppy to me, especially considering this is already v3 of their Odata web service standard.

Comment: At the time OData was created, XML was still king. Atom (XML) was the primary OData serialization format. The use of CSDL in OData follows from Microsoft's investment in EF and EDM, and OData's dependency on the latter. Now that JSON is ascendant, there is [interest in adopting Swagger/OpenAPI](https://issues.oasis-open.org/browse/ODATA-907) for representing metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Since the specific metadata you want is identified by a fragment appended to the metadata URI, you must fetch the entire `$metadata` document and then dereference the fragment on the client.

The good news is that the fragment dereferencing is pretty straightforward. A fragment like `#customer` specifies an `EntityType` element whose `Name` attribute has the value `customer`. Similarly, `#customer/@someprop` maps to a `Property` element whose `Name` attribute is `someprop`.