# Query metadata for EntitySet in Dynamics 365 for Operations

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7, dynamics-365-operations

When querying https://orgURL/data/Customers. I receive a list with customers.

How can I find out the properties/attributes of a Customer, without querying all metadata -> /data/$metadata

Comment: You might want to look at a similar thread [Fetching $metadata for a specific collection or entity with Odata web services in Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2016](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543769/fetching-metadata-for-a-specific-collection-or-entity-with-odata-web-services-i).

Answer (score 2):

No. The Specification define `$metadata` for the `service root` only.

> OData services expose their entity model according to [OData-CSDL] at the metadata URL, formed by appending $metadata to the **service root URL**.

See http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752338

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get data for a specific customer you can add a filter to your OData URL, e.g.

[https://orgURL/data/Customers?$filter=CustomerAccount eq '***Your_Customer_Id***'](https://orgURL/data/Customers?$filter=CustomerAccount%20eq%20'Your_Customer_Id')